# Highlight row in HTML table in SQL if the row exists in another table

Tags: html, sql-server, xquery

I use this query to send alerts. I would like a row to be highlighted if a Group ID is in the #GroupsProcessed table, but not to show any additional columns.
The status is always the same for the whole group.

```
drop table #Test
drop table #GroupsProcessed

CREATE TABLE #Test (GroupID INT, UserID INT, Status VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES  (1,4357, 'A'),
        (1,3492, 'A'),
        (1,3576, 'A'),
        (2,2457, 'B'),
        (3,9458, 'C'),
        (3,8765, 'C'),
        (4,5835, 'D'),
        (5,6654, 'E'),
        (5,4739, 'E'),
        (5,1366, 'E')

CREATE TABLE #GroupsProcessed (GroupID INT, UserID INT)
INSERT INTO #GroupsProcessed
VALUES  (1,4357),
        (1,3492),
        (1,3576),
        (4,5835)
DECLARE @xmlBody        XML   


SET @xmlBody = (SELECT (SELECT DISTINCT  f.GroupID
                                        ,(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(10),UserID, 120)
                                                  FROM #Test u 
                                                  WHERE    f.GroupID = u.GroupID
                                                  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')) AS UserID
                                        ,Status
                        FROM #Test              f WITH(NOLOCK) 
                        LEFT JOIN #GroupsProcessed o WITH(NOLOCK) ON o.GroupID = f.GroupID 
                        FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root'))
                .query('<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><style>
                table <![CDATA[ {border-collapse: collapse; } ]]>
                th <![CDATA[ {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} ]]>
                th, td <![CDATA[ { text-align: center; padding: 8px;} ]]>
                tr:nth-child(even) <![CDATA[ {background-color: #f2f2f2;} ]]>
                </style></head>
                <body><table border="1" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <thead><tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th> Group ID </th>
                <th> User ID </th>
                <th> Status </th>
                </tr></thead>
                <tbody>
                {for $row in /root/row
                let $pos := count(root/row[. << $row]) + 1
                return <tr align="center" valign="center">
                <td>{$pos}</td>
                <td>{data($row/GroupID)}</td>
                <td>{data($row/UserID)}</td>        
                <td>{data($row/Status)}</td>    
                </tr>}
                </tbody></table></body></html>'));
```

Result I have

[image]

Result I would like to have

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Notable points:

- Added `o.GroupID AS highlight` to the `SELECT` clause.
- Added special **yellow** class to the CSS section in the XQuery.
- Added dynamic attribute class to the `<tr>` element based on the presence of the
  `<highlight>` tag.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE  (GroupID INT, UserID INT, Status VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES  
(1,4357, 'A'),
(1,3492, 'A'),
(1,3576, 'A'),
(2,2457, 'B'),
(3,9458, 'C'),
(3,8765, 'C'),
(4,5835, 'D'),
(5,6654, 'E'),
(5,4739, 'E'),
(5,1366, 'E');

DECLARE @GroupsProcessed TABLE  (GroupID INT, UserID INT)
INSERT INTO @GroupsProcessed VALUES  
(1,4357),
(1,3492),
(1,3576),
(4,5835);

DECLARE @xmlBody XML   

SET @xmlBody = (SELECT (
SELECT DISTINCT  f.GroupID
    ,(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(10),UserID, 120)
                FROM @Test AS u 
                WHERE f.GroupID = u.GroupID
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS UserID
    ,Status, o.GroupID AS highlight
FROM @Test AS f 
LEFT JOIN @GroupsProcessed AS o ON o.GroupID = f.GroupID 
FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style>
        table <![CDATA[ {border-collapse: collapse; } ]]>
        th <![CDATA[ {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} ]]>
        th, td <![CDATA[ { text-align: center; padding: 8px;} ]]>
        tr.yellow td <![CDATA[ {background-color: yellow;} ]]>
    </style></head>
<body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th> Group ID </th>
            <th> User ID </th>
            <th> Status </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {for $row in /root/row
        let $pos := count(root/row[. << $row]) + 1
        return <tr align="center" valign="center">
        {if ($row/highlight) then attribute class {"yellow"} else ()}
        <td>{$pos}</td>
        <td>{data($row/GroupID)}</td>
        <td>{data($row/UserID)}</td>        
        <td>{data($row/Status)}</td>    
    </tr>}
    </tbody>
</table>
</body></html>'));

SELECT @xmlBody;
```

**Output in a browser**

[image]